# d3 - axis ticks not working unlike tickValues

Tags: d3.js

I made bar chart that has x-axis on time based and It worked with tickValues().

```
xAxis.tickFormat( customTimeFormat )
     .tickValues( xScale.domain()
     .filter( function( d, i ) {
          // return true or false by some process
     });
```

It works well as I expect, but when I made axis with ticks, it didn't work.

```
xAxis.tickFormat( customTimeFormat ).ticks(4);
```

How should I set ticks in axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to set ticks as a time intervals

```
xAxis.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%H:%M")).ticks(d3.timeHour, 1);
```

This code create ticks for each hour on a timeline. Also can be changed to d3.timeDay, d3.timeMonth, etc.